# JavaScript not running in HTML document upon form submission

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jsfiddle

I'm simply setting up a static website form submission. I've been using this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hussainanjar/qvna2se8/) as a template to add a submission button response. Admittedly, my JavaScript isn't where it needs to be yet, but I believe that the JavaScript here is supposed to alert me about the status of the submission when the submit button is clicked. At the current moment, it doesn't seem to work, preventing submission at all when I include the script at the bottom of my HTML document.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-half">
      <form action="https://api.staticforms.xyz/submit" method="post" id="staticform">
        <!-- Replace with your StaticForms accessKey -->
        <input type="hidden" name="accessKey" value="______">
        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Test from jsfiddle">
        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">Name</label>
          <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">Email</label>
          <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">Message</label>
          <div class="control">
            <textarea class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Enter Your Message" required></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="button is-primary" type="Submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's my JavaScript at the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
$("#staticform").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.staticforms.xyz/submit', // url where to submit the request
    type: "POST", // type of action POST || GET
    dataType: 'json', // data type
    data: $("#staticform").serialize(), // post data || get data
    success: function(result) {
      // you can see the result from the console
      // tab of the developer tools
      alert(JSON.parse(result));
    },
    error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
      alert(xhr, resp, text);
    }
  })
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. It seems to work in the JSFiddle, but does nothing on my end. When I remove the script completely the submission goes through but doesn't prompt me with a status.

I get the following error in the console:

> Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Any ideas? Ultimately, I want a way to demonstrate form status upon clicking the submit button.

Comment: In JSON.parse(result); check the data "result" before parsing, most likely its not a JSON string.

Comment: When you're setting `dataType: 'json'` in AJAX parameters, it tells [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) to parse the response result to JSON, you should not try to re-parse it.

Comment: First awful this is wrong. You double load the same code

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

Delete the second line for performance reasons.